# Custom Parameters & Custom URL for each keyword in Google Adwords

Tags: google-ads, bing

In Bing Ads, there is a nice functionality that allows me to add custom parameters and custom destination URL to keywords, and include them in my ads dynamically.

For example:

[image: keyword + parameters + custom destination URL]

Then I can create an ad such as:

[image: ad with placeholder]

Now if someone types in `iphone gold` in the search engine, he will see this ad:

[image: ad preview]

And if he clicks on the ad, he will go directly to the page for the product he was looking for, thanks to the custom destination URL.

**Is there an equivalent functionality in Google Adwords?**

I could not find any such thing, so far. I thought I had found it when I discovered the [custom parameter](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6076199?hl=en) column, but it looks like these parameters can only be used to dynamically build the destination URL, not the ad text, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now doing the same thing on Google AdWords. The answer is twofold:

### Custom destination URL

This can be set using the Final URL column directly:

[image: Final URL]

### Custom parameters

This can be set in the Business Data section, by creating an Ad Customizer Data feed:

[image: Ad Customizer]

The data feed can contain several columns, for example a `Products` feed could contain `Name` and `Price` columns:

[image: Ad Customizer example]

Unlike Bing Ads, custom ad parameters can be set at keyword, ad group or campaign level. This is both more powerful, and more complicated to maintain.

Note that the first items seem to have to be created by uploading a spreadsheet (AdWords offers a template to download). Further items can be added by uploading another spreadsheet, or from the user interface:

[image: Add Items]

Ad Customizer data feeds can then be used in ads, using the `{=Feed name.Column name}` syntax:

[image: Sample Ad]

A default text can also be provided, in case there is no matching entry in the feed:

```
{=Feed name.Column name:Default text}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer this, I'm sure it will be helpful to others in the future. Nice job on both the question and answer too!